# If one form filled, the others is not required in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have this model:

```
from django.db import models

class Summarizer(models.Model):

    url = models.URLField()
    text = models.TextField()
```

and this form:

```
class SummarizerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Summarizer
        fields = ['url', 'text']
        labels = {'url':'', 'text':''}
        widgets = {
            'url': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 1}),
            'text': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 100, 'rows': 12}),
        }
```

I want to make it **if the url is filled, the text is not required. Vice versa.**

I've tried this and it requires both of them to be filled:

```
class Summarizer(models.Model):

    url = models.URLField(blank=True)
    text = models.TextField(blank=True)

    if url:
        url = models.URLField()

    elif text:
        text = models.TextField()
```

It should only require one of the forms, not both.

What can I do?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should rewrite your forms clean method, try to get your fields using cleaned_data and return an error of both are empty.

```
class SummarizerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    def clean(self):
    """Access errors in template with
        'for error in <field>.errors:'
    """

        cleaned_data = super(SummarizerForm, self).clean()
        url = cleaned_data.get('url')
        text = cleaned_data.get('text')

        if url ="" and text= "":
            message_error = forms.ValidationError("Fill one of them")
            self.add_error('url', message_error)
            self.add_error('text', message_error)
```